# Composing Database.Esqueleto queries, conditional joins and counting

Tags: sql, haskell, yesod

How can I compose [Database.Esqueleto](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-1.2) queries in a modular way such that after defining a "base" query and the corresponding result set, I can restrict the result set by adding additional inner joins and where expressions.

Also, how can I convert the base query that returns a list of entities (or field tuples) into a query that counts the result set since the base query is not executed as such, but a modified version of it with LIMIT and OFFSET.

The following incorrect Haskell code snippet adopted from [the Yesod Book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) hopefully clarifies what I'm aiming at.

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies, OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, FlexibleContexts #-}
import qualified Database.Persist as P
import qualified Database.Persist.Sqlite as PS
import Database.Persist.TH
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Data.Conduit
import Control.Monad.Logger
import Database.Esqueleto
import Control.Applicative

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Person
    name String
    age Int Maybe
    deriving Show
BlogPost
    title String
    authorId PersonId
    deriving Show
Comment
    comment String
    blogPostId BlogPostId
|]

main :: IO ()
main = runStdoutLoggingT $ runResourceT $ PS.withSqliteConn ":memory:" $ PS.runSqlConn $ do
    runMigration migrateAll

    johnId <- P.insert $ Person "John Doe" $ Just 35
    janeId <- P.insert $ Person "Jane Doe" Nothing

    jackId <- P.insert $ Person "Jack Black" $ Just 45
    jillId <- P.insert $ Person "Jill Black" Nothing

    blogPostId <- P.insert $ BlogPost "My fr1st p0st" johnId
    P.insert $ BlogPost "One more for good measure" johnId
    P.insert $ BlogPost "Jane's" janeId

    P.insert $ Comment "great!" blogPostId

    let baseQuery = select $ from $ \(p `InnerJoin` b) -> do 
        on (p ^. PersonId ==. b ^. BlogPostAuthorId)
        where_ (p ^. PersonName `like` (val "J%"))
        return (p,b)

    -- Does not compile
    let baseQueryLimited = (,) <$> baseQuery <*> (limit 2)

    -- Does not compile
    let countingQuery = (,) <$> baseQuery <*> (return countRows)

    -- Results in invalid SQL 
    let commentsQuery = (,) <$> baseQuery
                <*> (select $ from $ \(b `InnerJoin` c) -> do
                        on (b ^. BlogPostId ==. c ^. CommentBlogPostId)
                        return ())

    somePosts <- baseQueryLimited
    count <- countingQuery
    withComments <- commentsQuery
    liftIO $ print somePosts
    liftIO $ print ((head count) :: Value Int)
    liftIO $ print withComments
    return ()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `LIMIT` and `COUNT`, hammar's answer is entirely correct so I'll not delve into them.  I'll just reiterate that once you use `select` you'll not be able to change the query in any way again.

For `JOIN`s, currently you are not able to do a `INNER JOIN` with a query that was defined in a different `from` (nor `(FULL|LEFT|RIGHT) OUTER JOIN`s).  However, you *can* do implicit joins.  For example, if you have defined:

```
baseQuery = 
  from $ \(p `InnerJoin` b) -> do 
  on (p ^. PersonId ==. b ^. BlogPostAuthorId)
  where_ (p ^. PersonName `like` val "J%")
  return (p, b)
```

Then you may just say:

```
commentsQuery = 
  from $ \c -> do
  (p, b) <- baseQuery
  where_ (b ^. BlogPostId ==. c ^. CommentBlogPostId)
  return (p, b, c)
```

Esqueleto then will generate something along the lines of:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM Comment, Person INNER JOIN BlogPost
ON    Person.id = BlogPost.authorId
WHERE Person.name LIKE "J%"
AND   BlogPost.id = Comment.blogPostId
```

Not pretty but gets the job done for `INNER JOIN`s.  If you need to do a `OUTER JOIN` then you'll have to refactor your code so that all the `OUTER JOIN`s are in the same `from` (note  that you can do an implicit join between `OUTER JOIN`s just fine).

Comment: Thanks for filling in the gaps and providing a conclusive answer.

Comment: I should also note that in `commentsQuery` you could also use `baseQuery` before using `from` just fine.

Comment: Also, please report as a bug any esqueleto query that results in invalid SQL so that we may investigate its roots.  The one you saw has  to do with the treatment of `()`, a known-but-not-fixed bug.  As a workaround you could do something such as `return (val True)`.

Comment: `esqueleto-1.2.1` should fix your problem with `return ()` without needing any workarounds =).

Comment: Thanks for the additional tips and for the bug fix. The "conditional joins" I'm referring to in the title means that I have a number of joins that may or may not be used in the query to filter the result. For now it seems that inner joins are enough, so I can use the implicit join syntax. However, I cannot compose them as you described because the next query composition step needs to specify the entities of the previous query, e.g. "(p,b) <- baseQuery" as above. What I can do is to include all from-statements in the same do-block and to use case-statements to conditionally include them.

Comment: I've just seen the code you're generating on `yesod-dsl`, for now I guess it's the best solution.  I'd like to have some kind of support for those "broken" queries but I haven't come up with a way of doing them yet.

Answer (score 9):

Looking at the documentation and the type of `select`:

```
select :: (...) => SqlQuery a -> SqlPersistT m [r]
```

It's clear that upon calling `select`, we leave the world of pure composable queries (`SqlQuery a`) and enter the world of side effects (`SqlPersistT m [r]`). So we simply need to compose before we `select`.

```
let baseQuery = from $ \(p `InnerJoin` b) -> do 
      on (p ^. PersonId ==. b ^. BlogPostAuthorId)
      where_ (p ^. PersonName `like` (val "J%"))
      return (p,b)

let baseQueryLimited = do r <- baseQuery; limit 2; return r
let countingQuery    = do baseQuery; return countRows

somePosts <- select baseQueryLimited
count     <- select countingQuery
```

This works for limiting and counting. I haven't figured out how to do it for joins yet, but it looks like it should be possible.

Comment: Thanks for solving the problem partially. In my use case I need to compose joins, too, so for the time being I'll resort to concatenating raw SQL strings.

Comment: Cheers @hammar.  For anyone else who runs into trouble getting the countingQuery version of this to compile: I had to specify the result type, which (for my Persistent configuration) is `[Value Int64]`.  I.e. it evaluates to a singleton list whose member is the count.