# Counting rows with esqueleto

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent, esqueleto

I am trying to count the rows of an inner-join with Esqueleto (version 2.1.2.1). Unfortunately, my code doesn't compile and I don't understand why. I looked at the following examples of how to do this but couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong: [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595892/composing-database-esqueleto-queries-conditional-joins-and-counting), [example2](https://www.haskell.org/pipermail/web-devel/2012/002621.html).

My schema looks like this (simplified):

```
User
Game
  state
Player
  user UserId Maybe
  game GameId
```

Users can register on the site to play games. You can also play without registering. Hence, there is a separate table `Player`. A game has a state. It can be `Ongoing`, or some form of game-over. I now want to count all ongoing games that a user is playing in.

The following SQL-query does that just fine (for a fixed userId of 1):

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM Player INNER JOIN Game
ON Player.game = Game.id
WHERE Player.user = 1 AND game.state = "Ongoing"
```

However, the following Esqueleto query does not compile:

```
[count1] <- runDB $ E.select                                    -- Line 25
                  $ E.from $ \(player `E.InnerJoin` game) -> do
                      E.on $ player^.PlayerGame E.==. game^.GameId
                      E.where_ $
                          player^.PlayerUser E.==. E.just (E.val userId) E.&&.
                          game^.GameState E.==. E.val MyGame.Ongoing
                      return (game, player)
                      return E.countRows                        -- Line 32
```

The error message reads like this:

```
Handler/ListUserGames.hs:25:23:
    No instance for (E.SqlSelect (expr0 (E.Value a0)) r0)
      arising from a use of ‘E.select’
    The type variables ‘r0’, ‘expr0’, ‘a0’ are ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance (E.SqlSelect a ra, E.SqlSelect b rb) =>
               E.SqlSelect (a, b) (ra, rb)
        -- Defined in ‘Database.Esqueleto.Internal.Sql’
      instance (E.SqlSelect a ra, E.SqlSelect b rb, E.SqlSelect c rc) =>
               E.SqlSelect (a, b, c) (ra, rb, rc)
        -- Defined in ‘Database.Esqueleto.Internal.Sql’
      instance (E.SqlSelect a ra, E.SqlSelect b rb, E.SqlSelect c rc,
                E.SqlSelect d rd) =>
               E.SqlSelect (a, b, c, d) (ra, rb, rc, rd)
        -- Defined in ‘Database.Esqueleto.Internal.Sql’
      ...plus 13 others
    In the expression: E.select
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘E.select
       $ E.from
         $ \ (player `E.InnerJoin` game)
             -> do { E.on $ player ^. PlayerGame E.==. game ^. GameId;
                     E.where_
                     $ player ^. PlayerUser E.==. E.just (E.val userId)
                       E.&&. game ^. GameState E.==. E.val MyGame.Ongoing;
                     .... }’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      [count1] <- runDB
                  $ E.select
                    $ E.from
                      $ \ (player `E.InnerJoin` game)
                          -> do { E.on $ player ^. PlayerGame E.==. game ^. GameId;
                                  E.where_
                                  $ player ^. PlayerUser E.==. E.just (E.val userId)
                                    E.&&. game ^. GameState E.==. E.val MyGame.Ongoing;
                                  .... }

Handler/ListUserGames.hs:32:32:
    No instance for (E.Esqueleto query0 expr0 backend0)
      arising from a use of ‘E.countRows’
    The type variables ‘query0’, ‘expr0’, ‘backend0’ are ambiguous
    Note: there is a potential instance available:
      instance E.Esqueleto E.SqlQuery E.SqlExpr SqlBackend
        -- Defined in ‘Database.Esqueleto.Internal.Sql’
    In the first argument of ‘return’, namely ‘E.countRows’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: return E.countRows
    In the expression:
      do { E.on $ player ^. PlayerGame E.==. game ^. GameId;
           E.where_
           $ player ^. PlayerUser E.==. E.just (E.val userId)
             E.&&. game ^. GameState E.==. E.val MyGame.Ongoing;
           return (game, player);
           return E.countRows }
```

However, the exact same query works if I remove the `countRows`. I.e. the following code compiles and does what I want it to do.

```
ongoing <- runDB $ E.select
                 $ E.from $ \(player `E.InnerJoin` game) -> do
                     E.on $ player^.PlayerGame E.==. game^.GameId
                     E.where_ $
                       player^.PlayerUser E.==. E.just (E.val userId) E.&&.
                       game^.GameState E.==. E.val MyGame.Ongoing
                     E.orderBy [E.desc $ game^.GameLastActionTime]
                     E.limit pagelen
                     E.offset $ max 0 $ (page1 - 1) * pagelen
                     return (game, player)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the Esqueleto code above is correct. The error was in another part of the code where a lack of restrictions caused type-ambiguity.

Comment: What was the type ambiguity? I am having this same problem but don't know where to add extra restrictions

Comment: @Agumander I'm afraid it's been a long time and I don't remember what exactly the issue was. However, looking at the code now, it seems that changing `count1` to `E.Value count1` in the pattern binding should help.

Comment: This led to a breakthrough! In my case I had additionally specify [E.Value (count1 :: Int)] since it was later passed to show. Thank you!